# How to rebuild fstab automatically

Tags: 10.04, command-line, hard-drive, fstab

I accidentally removed all the entries from the fstab files while doing a backup (Yeah, I know ;)).

I would like to know if there is a way to rebuild it with the current mount options, since I did not restart the server since the deletion. If there is no such program, could anybody help me rebuild it.

Using [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1362835), I have found the command to show the current setup, but I don't know what to do with it.

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="3fc55e0f-a9b3-4229-9e76-ca95b4825a40" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="718e611d-b8a3-4f02-a0cc-b3025d8db54d" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Files_Server_Int" UUID="02fc2eda-d9fb-47fb-9e60-5fe3073e5b55" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="41e60bc2-2c9c-4104-9649-6b513919df4a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Expansion Drive" UUID="782042B920427E5E" TYPE="ntfs" 


$ cat /etc/mtab
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
none /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /home ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/Files_Server ext4 rw 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /media/Expansion\040Drive fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/yvoyer/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=yvoyer 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /media/Backup500 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,sync,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions 0 0
/dev/sr0 /media/DIR-615 iso9660 ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/cdrapeau/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=cdrapeau 0 0
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I don't know of an automated way to restore it, but from your paste, created by hand..

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0  0
UUID=3fc55e0f-a9b3-4229-9e76-ca95b4825a40 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=718e611d-b8a3-4f02-a0cc-b3025d8db54d none swap sw 0 0 
UUID=41e60bc2-2c9c-4104-9649-6b513919df4a /home ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=02fc2eda-d9fb-47fb-9e60-5fe3073e5b55 /media/Files_Server ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Please wait for a couple of other people review and approve this before you blindly copy and reboot with it, a second set of eyes is always good ;)

I've left out sdd and sr0 as they look like they're done by gvfs.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't specify anything about cd-rom "/media/cdrom/", is it normal?

Comment: Sorry, should have said, I'll edit my answer. Yes I left that out intentionally too, as it's also handled by gvfs, automatically mounted when you insert a disc.

Comment: Is it better to restart or to run `mount -a`. With the `mount -a` option, could it break everything, or will it gives me warnings? Thanks very much.

Comment: `mount -a` will do precisely nothing if the lines in fstab are already mounted. You should see exactly zero output. So yes, I think you can safely try that. If you do get any messages it indicates an fstab line might be wrong. It is very unlikely to break anything though.

Answer (score 10):

**Disks** GUI program controls `fstab`. You can go there and put your partitions mount options on automatic by switching it off and on again. I think it will rebuild your `fstab` to the default mode.

Comment: The OP was waiting on answer to reboot his server almost 5 years ago....

Comment: @OrganicMarble if the asker was the only person the answers were here for, the accept button could just be a delete post button.

Answer (score 3):

```
blkid | grep /dev/sd | sed -e 's/:.* UUID/;UUID/' -e 's/ TYPE.*//' | while read re; do sed -i "s;$re;" /etc/fstab; done
```

This ^ cmd works for me quite well.

Comment: This gives me `s' command at char 12 and 102

Answer (score 0):

Using the Disks program (as suggested by Dead) worked for me. After selecting the partition I wanted to add to fstab, I used "Edit Mount Options..." and then selected "Mount on startup".