# How do I delete Windows files from Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, files

OS: 17.10 and Win10.

I am dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu. I can read and execute all files from my Windows partition. I can't delete them from Thunar, though. I ran as sudo and got the same result.

They're both on the same hard drive, but obviously partitioned. Is there any way I can delete Windows files from Ubuntu, or do I have to log into Windows to do that? I don't care about system safety, I'm working on reducing my files so I can eventually just delete the Windows partition completely.

**EDIT:** Windows is mounted. When I unmount it, I can't read or execute the files, let alone delete them.

**EDIT #2:** When trying to delete from the command line, I get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'file.exe': Read-only file system
```

When running the command `mount`, I get a lot of output back:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3993752k,nr_inodes=998438,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=804052k,mode=755)
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13322)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_86.snap on /snap/mailspring/86 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/atom_109.snap on /snap/atom/109 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_77.snap on /snap/mailspring/77 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/brackets_21.snap on /snap/brackets/21 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hugo_1012.snap on /snap/hugo/1012 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3604.snap on /snap/core/3604 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3440.snap on /snap/core/3440 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vscode_21.snap on /snap/vscode/21 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/brackets_46.snap on /snap/brackets/46 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_96.snap on /snap/mailspring/96 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/atom_76.snap on /snap/atom/76 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/atom_106.snap on /snap/atom/106 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vscode_20.snap on /snap/vscode/20 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /media/radhika/System type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda3 on /media/radhika/Windows type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=804048k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vscode_22.snap on /snap/vscode/22 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
```

I tried to get the output of /etc/fstab, the system says that folder does not exist.

Comment: "I can't delete them from Thunar" – What happens when you try? Any error messages? If so what do they say *exactly*? You can select, copy and paste most dialogue texts in Ubuntu.

Comment: The option is simply grayed out. Windows is on an NTFS filesystem, if that helps.

Comment: Try deleting from the console (but be careful); do you get error messages, and which? And what's the output of the command `mount`? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: Can you include the contents of **/etc/fstab** in your question?

Comment: Updated to answer all of the above questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal
Type `sudo mount -o remount,rw /disk/location /mount/location`

You just unmounted and remounted your disk as R/W so anyone can read - write. Make sure to do `sudo umount /disk/location` when you are done, because if anyone wants to do harm they can write to the disk now!

Try `lsblk` for your disk location and when you want to regenerate your fstab, just reboot.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. In hindsight, I should've realized it was a permission issue. I thought being able to execute would mean I should be able to delete the files.

Comment: rebooting does not regenerate `/etc/fstab`. Did you mean something else that I am not aware of?

Comment: maybe try https://askubuntu.com/questions/81726/how-to-rebuild-fstab-automatically

Comment: 1. unmount ur window directory `sudo umount -f /media/sami/OS\ WIN7`, 2. Force remove `sudo rm -rf sami/OS\ WIN7`