# Failure to Boot: Journal version is not supported by this e2fsck

Tags: boot, fstab, initramfs, fsck

My computer is failing to boot regularly, and I am entering the initramfs screen. The command `exit` outputs the following.

> /dev/nvme0n1p2: Journal version not supported by this e2fsck.
>
> /dev/nvme0n1p2: UNEXPECTED INCONSITENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e. without -a or -p options)
>
> fsck exited with status code 4
>
> The root filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p2 requires a manual fsck

Also, the file `/etc/fstab` is empty. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: If fstab is empty what else is missing or is it just you cannot see it because fsck required? If it takes more than an hour to fix, often better to just reinstall and restore from your backup. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting And from live installer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rebuild fstab automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81726/how-to-rebuild-fstab-automatically) and [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/q/697190/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)